# how to integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}+e^x+1}}$

Tags: integration

I am having troubles with this integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}+e^x+1}}dx.$$

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try to substitute $u  = e^x$.

Answer (score 7):

$\bf{My\; Solution}::$ We can write it as $\displaystyle \int\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}+e^{-2x}}}dx\;$

Now Let $e^{-x}=t\;,$ Then $e^{-x}dx = -dt$.
So our integral becomes $\displaystyle - \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+t+1}}dt$

Which is equal to $\displaystyle = -\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}}dt$

Now Using $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx = \ln \left|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right|+\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Your very first integral's central summand in the denominator must be $\;e^{-x}\;$

Comment: Are you sure about the substitution? Shouldnt the integral after substitution be: `- int t / sqrt( t^2 + t + 1 )*( dt / e ^ -x )` ?

Comment: Or is it possible not to substitute every `e ^ -x` with `t` so you get: `- int e ^ -x / sqrt( t^2 + t + 1 )*( dt / e ^ -x )`