# Is there another way to solve this integral? (A bit long for my method)

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x+e^{2x}+1}}dx$$

My attempts, 
Substitute $u=e^x$ and $du=e^xdx$

$$=\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2+u+1}}$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{(u+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}}$$

Substitute $s=u+\frac{1}{2}$ and $ds=du$

$$=\int \frac{1}{(s-\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{s^2+\frac{3}{4}}}$$

Substitute $s=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\tan (p)$ and $ds=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sec ^2(p)dp$.

Then $\sqrt{s^2+\frac{3}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{3\tan ^2(p)}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sec (p)$ and $p=\tan ^{-1}(\frac{2s}{\sqrt{3}})$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\int \frac{2\sec (p)}{\sqrt{3}(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\tan (p)-\frac{1}{2})}dp$$

$$=\int \frac{\sec (p)}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\tan (p)-\frac{1}{2}}dp$$

Substitute $w=\tan (\frac{p}{2})$ and $dw=\frac{1}{2}dp\sec ^2(\frac{p}{2})$

$$=\int \frac{2}{(1-w^2)(-\frac{\sqrt{3}w}{w^2-1}-\frac{1}{2})}dw$$

$$=\int \frac{4}{w^2+2\sqrt{3}w-1}dw$$

$$=4\int \frac{1}{(w+\sqrt{3})^2-1}dw$$

Substitute $v=w+\sqrt{3} and $dv=dw$

$$=4\int \frac{1}{v^2-4}dv$$

$$=4\int -\frac{1}{4(1-\frac{v^2}{4}})dv$$

$$=-\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{4}}dv$$

Substitute $z_1=\frac{v}{2}$ and $dz_1=\frac{1}{2}dv$

$$=-2\int \frac{1}{1-z_1^2}dz_1$$

$$=-2\tanh^{-1}(z_1)+c$$

$$=-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{v}{2})+c$$

$$=-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}(w+\sqrt{3}))+c$$

$$-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}(\tan (\frac{p}{2})+\sqrt{3}))+c$$

$$-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{3(\sqrt{4s^2+3}+\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{3}s}{2\sqrt{12s^2+9}+6})+c$$

$$=-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{3\sqrt{u^2+u+1}+\sqrt{3}u+2\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{u^2+u+1}+3})+c$$

$$=-2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{3\sqrt{e^x+e^{2x}+1+\sqrt{3}e^x+2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{e^x+e^{2x}+1}+3})+c$$

How to simplify my answer to $x-\ln(2\sqrt{e^x+e^{2x}+1}+e^x+2)+c$? Is there another way to solve this integral as this method is a bit long. ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212692/how-to-integrate-frac1-sqrte2xex1

Comment: A technique that is powerful and unfortunately little taught is the method of Euler Substitution (please see Wikipedia).

Comment: Please check before you post a query that may it has been asked...